# Razor generates incorrect HTML for arrays after web publishing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2015, model-binding

I have an array of `Ticket` objects in my ViewModel, which I show an editor for:

```
<tbody class="ticket-entry" id="ticket-body">
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Tickets)
</tbody>
```

The names in inputs generated when testing locally are always correct, for example:

```
<input id="Tickets_0__RouteNumber" name="Tickets[0].RouteNumber" type="text" value="5454">
```

However, after publishing to another server, MVC generates different names, which fail model binding. The same section generated after publishing looks like the following:

```
<input id="Tickets_Tickets_0__RouteNumber" name="Tickets.Tickets[0].RouteNumber" type="text" value="5454">
```

Note that the property name has been duplicated here.

This is happening for all arrays on the form, and can be duplicated on  Windows Server 2008 R2 and Windows Server 2012 R2. My local version is pointing to the same database as production, and I've tried publishing debug  versions, disabling precompiling, as well as testing in IIS Express and IIS Local, but the results are consistent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somehow this was caused by extra files still being present from a previous version. Enabling `Remove additional files at destination.` during the publishing step fixed the issue, although I'm still unsure how this could have caused incorrect HTML to be generated.